# this is my error how to fix this?? when i click on textfield this error appear

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRGy5.jpg)

this my code

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
            title: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 20,bottom: 20,),

              child: TextField(
                autofocus: false,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20),
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'گەڕان',
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => _searchInputController.clear(),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                    ),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 5.0,top: 10.0)),
                onSubmitted:  (value) {
                  _filterList(value);
                },
                controller: _searchInputController,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: PLEASE ... do not post mages of code/data/errors. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

I've had this bug for a while too. It seems like an internal Flutter bug which we can't do much about. I think you can bypass it by changing the internal structure of a TextField, but it's not worth the effort since the bug doesn't cause anything bad.

Since Flutter 2 I don't have this error anymore, maybe try updating.

Comment: already updated tell me how to make textfield by another way

Comment: What do you mean? 

What I wanna say is that even though you have that error, it's no big deal, don't worry about it (unless you see something is not behaving correctly of course)

Comment: sorry well done thank you